# summation notation of elements in several different (sub)sets

Tags: summation, notation

If there are two different sets $A$ and $B$, and $A\cap B= \emptyset$, then sum of all elements in both sets might be written as,

$$\sum_{a\in A}a+\sum_{b\in B}b$$

What I want to ask is, can I express the sum of all elements in both sets at once as following?

$$\sum_{x\in A\cup B}x$$

Or is there any other way to write it at once (for shortening)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, assuming that the sets are finite, *and* that $A\cap B = \emptyset$, then indeed:

$$\require{cancel}\begin{align}\sum\limits_{a\in A}a+\sum\limits_{b\in B}b ~~=&~ \sum\limits_{x\in A\cup B} x\cancelto{0}[color=silver]{+\sum\limits_{y\in A\cap B}y}\end{align}$$